# Insertar formula compleja en excel desde vba

Tags: excel, vba

¿Como puedo meter una formula como esta dentro de una celda en una hoja de excel desde VBA?

```
=SI.ERROR(SUMAPRODUCTO(1/CONTAR.SI(Bajas_780!C$2:INDICE(Bajas_780!C:C;CONTARA(Bajas_780!C:C));Bajas_780!C$2:INDICE(Bajas_780!C:C;CONTARA(Bajas_780!C:C))));"0")"
```

Esta formula si que funciona directamente en excel, sin embargo es parte de una automatización, pero al escribir previamente las hojas, sin estar creadas, entra en conflicto y no las identifica correctamente y se pierde el vinculo, por lo que cada vez tengo que entrar a la línea de formula de la celda para que haga el calculo.

Comment: Tarda uno más en descifrar lo que pretendes viendo la fórmula, que si lo explicas tú mismo. Me refiero a relatar lo que hace la fórmula. Calcular tal, cofiendo éste dato de ésta celda, haciendo ésto otro de ésta otra celda, etc. Un saludo

Comment: Probablemente el problema no sea la fórmula, sino el orden en el que se inserta en el código. Si nos pones el código es posible que podamos ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Para introducir formulas de excel en VBA, has de tener en cuenta que el nombre de las funciones usadas en la fórmula deben estar en idioma inglés, aunque tengas configurado el idioma local en cualquier otro.
En tu caso, por ejemplo, deberías comenzar la función con "=IF.ERROR(SUMPRODUCT(etc..."

Opcionalmente, si no sabes el nombre de todas las funciones en idioma inglés, puedes ponerlas en castellano (tal como harías introduciendo la fórmula directamente en la barra de fórmulas), pero entonces has de usar la propiedad "Range.FormulaLocal" en VBA, en vez de "Range.Formula".

Puedes aprender más aquí:
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.range.formulalocal

Comment: Buenas eso ya lo intente, poniendo todas las formulas en inglés, pero aún así no me reconocía la formula, igual lo acabe arreglando de otra forma.